# Linq to entities navigation properties complexities

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have 3 entities the middle one joins the outer two.
I have a value for RequestType1, what I need is the corrosponding values for RequestField1 using Linq. The value for RequestType1 is 2.

my classes look like this

```
 public partial class RequestField
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public int RequestField1 { get; set; }
    public string FieldContents { get; set; }

    public virtual FieldDefinition FieldDefinition { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}

public partial class FieldDefinition
{
    public FieldDefinition()
    {
        this.RequestFields = new HashSet<RequestField>();
        this.RequestTypes = new HashSet<RequestType>();
    }

    public int RequestField { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldReference { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestField> RequestFields { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestType> RequestTypes { get; set; }
}

public partial class RequestType
{
    public RequestType()
    {
        this.Requests = new HashSet<Request>();
        this.FieldDefinitions = new HashSet<FieldDefinition>();
    }

    public int RequestType1 { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FieldDefinition> FieldDefinitions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, that would something like this:

```
var requestFields = myRequestType.SelectMany(
                                   rt => rt.FieldDefinitions.SelectMany(
                                          fd => fd.RequestFields.Select(
                                               rf => rf.RequestField1)));
```

Comment: In the database I have a table with the 2 primary keys, where I created the entity it became navigation properties.

Comment: Which table are you talking about?

Comment: I have a table containing 2 primary keys RequestType and RequestField.

Comment: They join the requestType table and the fieldDefinition table

Comment: The name of the joining table is RequestTypeField

Comment: Is `RequestType1` the primary key in `RequestType`?

Comment: Yes, when I run this in sql I get the results I expect. SELECT        RequestField
FROM            RequestTypeField
WHERE        (RequestType = 2)

Comment: Does `RequestTypeField` have its own entity?

Comment: For some reason it didnt create an entity for it, rather it used its fields as navigation properties on the FieldDefinition entity